# Set Locales on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, utf-8, locale

Greetings: I want to set locales in Ubuntu. It currently has `en_US.UTF-8` and I want to change it to `es_ES.ISO-8859-1`. I added the locale by entering the command `sudo locale-gen "es_ES.ISO-8859-1"`

When i execute the following command, it says, among other things, `ISO-8859-1 up to date`, but it does not show me a menu for selecting a default locale:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

But when I execute the command `sudo update-locale LANG=es_ES.ISO-8859-1` and afterwards I execute `locale`, it still shows `LANG=es.ES_UTF-8`. The same is true for all variables that starts with `LC_` and the variable `LANGUAGE`. The commands don't show me any success or error message when executed.

I even edited manually the file `/etc/default/locale` to no avail.

When i examine the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, the locale es_ES.ISO-8859-1 is displayed.

What did i do wrong?

If it helps, I am not running the terminal as a root, but I can execute commands with `sudo`. Plus, the output of `uname -a` is:

> Linux SOL-05-LON-VPS01 3.13.0-48-generic #80~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 19:30:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux